# Text file manipulation - insert a newline character after the first two characters in a line

Tags: python, file

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
XX number number number
XY number number number
...
XN number number number
```

XX, XY etc have either 1 or 2 characters and the numbers can be either positive or negative, it doesn't really matter. What I would like to figure out (but I can't, for the life of me) is how to insert a newline after XX, XY etc so that my file would look like this:

```
XX  
number number number
XY  
number number number
...
XN
number number number
```

What I'd also want to do is to remove the whitespaces after every XX, XY but not the ones between the numbers. Everything I've tried until now only introduces newline characters after every 2 characters. I'm a super-beginner in Python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So XX and XY and whatnot always occur at the beginning of a line, always represent some integer, and there are no lines without?

Comment: XX, XY etc always occur at the beginning of a line (it's basically atoms and atom coordinates, so think of every line being for example C coordinateX coordinateY coordinateZ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) seems like a good choice, espcially if you want to modify every single line.

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            line = line.replace(' ', '\n', 1)
            output_file.write(line)
```

[`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) would be a good choice if you only want to modify some of the lines, and the choice of which lines to modify can be made with a regular expression:

```
import re
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            line = re.sub(r'(^[A-Z]+)\s+', r'\1\n', line)
            output_file.write(line)
```

`str.split()` might work, also, but it will disrupt any sequence of multiple spaces between the numbers:

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            line = line.split()
            output_file.write(line[0] + '\n')
            output_file.write(' '.join(line[1:]) + '\n')
```

Comment: thank you so much, you've made a chemist very happy! :)

Comment: does concatenating "\n" work for Windows?  Would you need to concatenate "\r\n"?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re   
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
        with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
            for line in input_file:
                splitter = re.search("\d", line).start()
                output_file.write(line[:splitter].strip() + "\n")
                output_file.write(line[splitter:])
```